# What are the datatypes available in asterisk server dial plan

Tags: asterisk

What are the datatypes available in asterisk server dial plan?

how to check the date type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asterisk dial plan language is weakly-typed (has no 'types' as such). All values are strings, but can be treated as numbers in some context (e.g. arithmetic expressions). The only way to check 'the type' is to use a regular expression to check the value.

There are some functions like [HASH](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+hash) or [SORT](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+sort) which seem to operate on some complex data types, but these are not main features of the language, but rather helpers for specific use cases.

Comment: is any application available for date comparition?

Answer (score 0):

No, in dialplan everything is a string. You can use AGI to check date or compare various things.

What exactly do you need? I'm guessing but maybe this will be useful: [How to include contexts based on time and date](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+tips+openhours)

Answer (score -1):

There is no type in dialplan, everything can be treated string variable.

But if required, you can always use your favorite programming language using AGI.